# Catch integer exceptions in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, integer-overflow, intel-fortran

Is there a way to catch integer exceptions with `gfortran` or `ifort` like there is for catching floating point exceptions?

Consider this simple program to calculate the factorial:

```
program factorial
  use, intrinsic :: iso_fortran_env 

  implicit none
  integer(8)          :: fac
  real(REAL64)        :: facR
  integer,parameter   :: maxOrder = 30
  integer             :: i

  fac = 1 ; facR = 1.e0_REAL64
  do i=2,maxOrder
    fac=fac*i ; facR=facR*real(i,REAL64)
    write(*,*) i, fac, facR
  enddo ! i

end program
```

At some point there will be an overflow - for `integer(8)` as shown here, it will occur at around 21. But without the calculation using floats as a reference I couldn't tell for sure...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing in the Fortran standard that deals with integer overflow.  As it stands you can't even rely on integers wrapping round when a computation exceeds the maximum value representable in the chosen kind.  So, while a test such as

```
huge(2_8)+1 < 0_8
```

is likely to work with most current compilers (at least the ones I have used recently) it's not guaranteed.

I am sure that neither Intel Fortran nor gfortran provide compiler-generated run-time checks for integer overflow either.  I'm not sure about other compilers but I'll be (pleasantly) surprised to learn that any of them do.

I think, therefore, that you have to proceed with your current approach.

Answer (score 2):

**gfortran** will catch integer overflow with *-ftrapv* flag, see man gcc:

> -ftrapv
>   This option generates traps for signed overflow on addition, subtraction, multiplication operations.

**ifort** does not seem to have that capability.

Comment: It was broken in some gfortran releases. See:https://blog.robertelder.org/gcc-signed-overflow-trapping-ftrapv-doesnt-work/